# How did a user receive 1000 reputation for a removed post?

Tags: support, reputation

I saw user who scored [1020 reputation in this week](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=week), so I checked their [reputation tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/91914/gnarf?tab=reputation&sort=post). There, I noticed a *strange* reputation entry; *they received +1000rep for a removed post..*

I thought they may have offered 1000 reputation bounty for a post, and due to the removal of the post the reputation was refunded to them. But seeing their [*"bounty offered"* page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/91914/gnarf?tab=bounties&sort=offered), there is no entry about such a post.

So if the post was indeed removed would the relevant information be also removed from the *"bounty offered"* page?

The queried reputation is:
 [rep](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6muw.png)

I do not have 10k reputation to see the removed post or its timeline.

Can anyone tell me what the actual reason behind this +1000 entry is?

Comment: There's two 500 rep bounties on answers to that question, I'm guessing they got refunded maybe? Screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/1qDfS

Comment: Jesus, how bad was the question that they received that much to remove it.

Comment: It's kind of strange that the bounties where refunded when the people who received them didn't get a corresponding correction but I guess this isn't a very common occurence.

Comment: The mods were looking at this an hour ago. We have no idea what's going on either.

Comment: @BDL: [Technically](https://xkcd.com/1475/), there were 2 `500` rep bounties.

Comment: @BoltClock simple case of bounties. Did you miss it, or am I missing something here?

Comment: @Shadow Wizard: Yes, specifically, if the bounties should have been refunded in this specific circumstance, considering those were bounties that were already awarded (with you being one of the winners, by the way). It might not be that simple.

Comment: @BoltClock but it is simple. Bounty is based on vote. Same way user who downvoted answer gets the -1 back when the answer is deleted, user who gave a bounty gets it back when the question is deleted. If the question is undeleted, points will be taken again. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard the point is though that the recipients of the bounties didn't lose the points. 1000 points have been magicked out thin air.

Comment: So if I really need an answer to a question, I post a reward of 500 points. After I got my answer I delete the questions to regain my points? sounds fishy - good thing nobody woul dever do that...

Comment: @ShadowWizard: the bounties were *awarded*. Over 5 years ago. Normally those that set the bounty would not see it returned after the bounty has been awarded already. I think this might be a bug instead, one involving the "deleted > 60 days since posting" rules for retaining post reputation.

Comment: @PatrickArtner you can't delete your own question once it get answer with upvotes, so it's pretty hard to abuse.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I don't think so. Feel free to report a bug in MSE (this isn't specific to SO), but I'm 99% sure it will get a response that it's by design. (Or just ask someone "official" in TL)

Comment: @ShadowWizard: I already poked the CMs to get a better explanation.

Comment: @MartijnPieters you can ask them to post reply to my MSE question then, so we'll have it written once and for all. :-)

Comment: @ShadowWizard: I'm first confirming this internally.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: but your question may be a dupe of [What happened to the 50 points bounty I awarded a user before my question was migrated to DBA?](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/140185), which Nick Craver tagged as 'status-bydesign', with an answer by Shog. The answer is still vaguely worded, and I'd like to have the exact rules written out or confirmed to be actively wrong (rather than a "that is how it works now, we don't know why" style statement).

Comment: @MartijnPieters I found that post because it's linked to at the bottom of [the bounty FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work).

Comment: @gparyani: note that the FAQ contradicts the behaviour: *The bounty is not given back to the user who awarded it*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters It no longer does.

Comment: @gparyani: no, it still does. It was edited, yes, but to add the normal 'reputation retention' rules for answers.

Comment: @MartijnPieters OK, think I can now agree it might be a bug. Did you ask Nick or Shog in TL to give official answer and put an end to the confusion?

Comment: @ShadowWizard: I asked Shog in the SO moderator room.

Comment: @gparyani while this is no doubt the current behavior, this might still be a bug (i.e. that's not the **intended** behavior). Let's see what Shog will say, if anything.

Comment: @MartijnPieters FR filed here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/306694/do-not-refund-bounty-on-question-deletion-if-reputation-would-be-kept-on-an-awar

Comment: I thought we were waiting for an answer from Shog?

Comment: @ivarni How did you take the screenshot of the whole page?

Comment: @Sankar Firefox has new screenshot capabilities including easy full-page screenshots.

Comment: @Sankar Chrome has that built in when you use the devtools. There's also numerous extensions for most browsers to do it.

Comment: Thanks @ivarni and wentz. I thought you have that much big monitor and i felt jealous about that :P

Comment: @wentz Not exactly new... Firefox has supported fullscreen screenshots for years.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

**Update:** As of February 13, 2018, this situation should not occur, and the user's reputation has been recalculated so that they haven't earned reputation from it. The feature request described in the last paragraph below has been implemented - reputation is no longer refunded if the awardee gets to keep it, per the second paragraph below. Also, previous such refunds that no longer qualify under the new rules have been revoked.

---

As Shadow said, the 1,000 reputation added to that account was because a single question where they had awarded two +500 reputation bounties was deleted. Whenever any question that previously had a bounty gets deleted for any reason, the bounty reputation gets returned to the bounty owner(s). This is what happened in this case. (Side note: if the question were to be undeleted, the user would lose the 1,000 reputation again.)

The reason why the answerers didn't lose their 500-rep bounties is because of a special rule in the system: if an answer has a score of at least 3 and has been visible for at least 60 days, any reputation change from that answer is kept upon deletion. This is intentional, because when an answer that meets those conditions is deleted, it's usually for reasons unrelated to the answer's quality.

There exists a [feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/306694/do-not-refund-bounty-on-question-deletion-if-reputation-would-be-kept-on-an-awar) on Meta Stack Exchange to not refund bounties upon deletion if the awardees would get to keep it due to the above rule.

Comment: I'd say this is actually a bug, as the bounties have been awarded over 5 years ago.

Comment: @MartijnPieters That's intentional, with the current design. You can file a feature request on MSE if you want this changed.

Comment: Those limitations **do** exist on questions. There was no reversal of the question reputation to the question asker, they got 7 * 5 + 1 * -2 == 33 points from votes on the question. Their *answer* posted to the same question was at +2 and they had the +20 for that subtracted on deletion.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Comment edited. But my points that's an intentional feature currently, and that if you want it changed you should file a feature request, still apply.

Comment: I'm quite familiar with these rules, as a moderator. The bounty refund is highly unusual and unexpected.

Comment: @MartijnPieters But not a bug.

Comment: @MartijnPieters https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145329/when-a-question-that-had-bounties-is-deleted-are-they-automatically-refunded

Comment: @ShadowWizard: but no confirmation this is by design.

Comment: @gparyani: this is not documented as the official policy and certainly flies in the face of my own experience with deleting posts for users with socks and bounty transfers.

Comment: @MartijnPieters [Yes it is.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172556/so-points-changed-50-for-no-reason).

Comment: No, I do think it is a bug. See [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221) as well: *Reputation changes from bounties, votes (both up and down), and acceptances on deleted posts (including answers to a deleted question) are nullified. (Exception: Reputation earned for posts with a score of 3 or higher, and where the post has been visible on the site for at least 60 days, is retained).* A bounty *awarded* is not reputation earned by the bounty setter.

Comment: @gparyani: *but it doesn't currently have an official response*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes it does. It's tagged [meta-tag:status-bydesign].

Comment: @gparyani: yes, it is interesting that Nick tagged it as such. So I'm getting some confirmation from the CMs. If it is status-bydesign I'll request it to be changed. Until then, I regard it as a bug.

Comment: I would have to agree with @MartijnPieters here.. If bounty is not removed from recipient then it makes no sense to give back to asker

Comment: @SurajRao I tend to agree, I don't really like this functionality of the system. While it's not a bug, I think it should be changed, and I'd support a feature request asking for it to be changed.

Comment: @SurajRao See my feature request here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/306694/do-not-refund-bounty-on-question-deletion-if-reputation-would-be-kept-on-an-awar

Comment: It's one of the very explicit points of the bounty system that once you offer the bounty, you say goodbye to that rep. Either someone will get (part of) it later, or it dissolves into the void. The fact that the bounty amount was given back to the person who offered it _while_ the beneficiary also kept theirs, surely cannot be a feature! Quoting [ChrisF](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/363014/how-a-user-received-1000-reputation-for-a-removed-post?cb=1#comment555247_363014): "*1000 points have been magicked out thin air.*". That _can't_ be a feature.

Comment: @AndrasDeak I agree with that; however, the broader fact that the bounty is always refunded to the owner when the question was deleted was dismissed as "by design". My MSE question above is a request to change this behavior, so that the bounty rep isn't refunded if the awardee got to keep it. By the way, I spoke to Shog in chat, and he said he'd ping the dev who marked it as that for more info.

Comment: @gparyani as Martijn has already noted, it's possible that Nick was simply wrong ;) A bug labelled a feature might still be a bug. The Powers that Be shall decide, I guess.

Comment: @AndrasDeak Shog said the same as well, in my chat with him. However, if I phrased my request as a bug, it could have been downvoted because of the prior dismissal of that behavior as "by design". I phrased it as a feature request to avoid that.

Comment: @AndrasDeak "A bug labelled a feature might still be a bug." You have obviously never had to deal with Internet Explorer.

Comment: So start with two accounts with 1000 rep.  Post a question.  Other account answers.  Give 500 point bounty on other account.  Wait 60 days.  Edit question to be horrible.  Close and delete question.  Repeat.  Seems way harder than just getting 50 upvotes.

Comment: The feature is fixed https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/306966/changes-to-bounty-rules-removal-of-double-rep-retention-blocking-of-owner-dele

Answer (score 14):

Yes, those are two bounties, 500 rep each:

> [image]

Users with less than 10k rep don't see deleted questions in the offered bounties list.

Comment: so does that mean users who were awarded bounties do not lose it.. but the ones who offer are refunded?

Comment: @SurajRao: Those users show no bounty rep in their profile, for that question.

Comment: @SurajRao they keep the bounty only if the answer had score of at least 3, and posted 60 days before the question was deleted. e.g. [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11490073/447356) qualifies, so I kept the rep indeed, and there is no rep change for me.

Comment: @Cerbrus well that's because the question is deleted and we don't get to see deleted posts in other user's profiles, except favorites and bounty list.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: You got to keep it? Did we just find a rep duplication glitch? Prepare for inflation followed by the bubble bursting ;-)

Comment: @Cerbrus yes I keep it. No glitch, no inflation... if the question will be undeleted at some point, the OP (or whoever started the bounty) will lose 1000 rep again.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: and the question asker retained their reputation for the question, but not their answer on the same post (the latter had a score of 2), as expected. What is *not* expected is to see the awarded bounties refunded to the bounty issuer.

Comment: Slightly off topic, but 6 offered bounties of 500 each add up to 3000, not 2000. That looks like a bug to me, but unfortunately I cannot verify it.

Comment: @Justastudent it counts only the undeleted bounties. As this very question proves, the deleted have no real effect on reputation any more, so excluding them from the sum is correct. The user lost only 2000 rep on bounties, not 3000.

Comment: @MartijnPieters If I downvote an answer with score >3 and then it gets deleted, I get back the 1 rep that I spent to downvote but the poster doesn't recover the 2 rep that it cost them. Isn't this the same thing? Namely, deletion of highly-upvoted content doesn't affect the rep of the poster to avoid deterring deletion, but rep spent *voting* on content that then gets deleted is always refunded.

Comment: Fair enough, @ShadowWizard. It just seemed weird to me that it counts deleted bounties in the number (6), but not the reputation. But I agree with your argument.

Comment: @Justastudent that's true, might be very minor bug, feel free to report on MSE and gain some rep... ;)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I don't know about "glitch", but there's certainly some degree of inflation, given that rep has been created from nothing. Of course, upvotes also create rep from nothing, so its not like its the end of the world.

Comment: I'm curious as to how/why the question was deleted. Do your ninja 10k powers reveal any info on that?

Comment: @StephenKennedy users with 10k rep can delete any closed question. The question was closed then deleted by ordinary high rep users.