Got 500 bounty earned 6 months ago removed off my account today
I answered a bountied question, and received the bounty, but the question and answers, shown below, were deleted 6 months after receiving the bounty:

This deletion resulted in loss of bounty reputation points, as shown below:

I have read some posts and rules changes regarding this, but what I understood was this behavior/issue was fixed. Please enlighten me if otherwise.

This (sometimes) happens when a bountied answer gets deleted. In this case, that appears to be because the question was deleted. I feel like this has to be a duplicate of something; trying to find an appropriate target at the moment.

The post in question, and a screenshot for <10k people.

As a start, you can CTRL+F for "delete" in the MSE FAQ.

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/363014/how-did-a-user-receive-1000-reputation-for-a-removed-post (if your post had a score of 3+, then the bounty wouldn't have been refunded).

I mean.. the question was entirely off topic. i'm surprised the rep wasn't lost sooner.

Looks like someone downvoted your answer to trigger the roomba; I'm honestly not against it on this occasion as the question doesn't meet any of the requirements to be on-topic on [so].

@KevinB I completely agree, and do not have a problem with question being deleted. But didn't get the logic behind returned bounty. Found related answers on meta, but they further confused me, e.g. here, and here.

All the reputation from gained/lost from post is usually reverted on deletion.

"But didn't get the logic behind returned bounty." -- Why should you get rewarded for answering a question that shouldn't have been posted in the first place? You should have known better that posting an answer to that.

I'm amazed that someone who's been a SO member for a couple of years with >5k rep would post such an off-topic question. But I'm even more amazed that they'd offer a 500 point bounty for such a question.

The only reason to have any kind of confusion about it is when you consider the bounty to be a reward... we really should stop calling it that. Reputation is not a reward/punishment system no matter what you do. A bounty is merely a reputation booster acting like peacock feathers, "Look at me! No don't look at that other question, look at me!". But after it has been collected the reputation points are just like any other. Leased, not your property, will be taken away if the bookkeeping requires it.

@PM2Ring Unfortunately, I'm not. I've seen plenty of users with 5 digit rep post obvious non-answers...people really need to learn basic rules.

@subdeveloper - “But didn't get the logic behind returned bounty.” - You answered an obviously out of scope question which was ultimately deleted. Why would you keep any reputation if the answer and question was deleted?

This kind of thing makes me think that bounties shouldn't be refunded to the bounty poster if the question was deleted ever, since you can just post an off-topic question, put up a TON of rep in bounties to get an answer despite being off-topic, and get those points back when the question gets deleted.

Funny thing, but you could have prevented the question from being deleted by upvoting one of the other answers.

You made the same mistake I far too often make, @PM2Ring , assuming people with reputation know what the site is actually for. Some of the (very) high reputation users are actually the worst examples. I met a 300k user the other day that stated that a question is on-topic because the tag the OP used had already existed on the site; even though the question had nothing to do with programming or tools used by programmers, and was about updating applications that had been installed via the Windows Store.

@ThomA It is certainly not an uncommon occurrence on meta, to get a... talking to from a high rep user asking for explanations why people are not acting according to their world view. Which then seems to stem from when the site was still in its infancy and ignores a great many site rules which are now so standard that even meta dwellers can kind of agree on how they work. It is fascinating how it can take so long for the bubble to finally burst.

@ipodtouch0218 - Asking a question and getting it deleted is a recipe to become question banned quickly

@SecurityHound not so sure about that given the context. If you can put up a ton of bounty, I don't think you are going to risk getting banned so quickly. Having a nice pool of reputation points acts like a shield.

When the question was deleted, all of its answers were deleted, yours included. According to this, reputation is kept for deleted posts only if the post scored over 3 and was visible for 60+ days. Your post met the second criteria but not the first.
The question was auto-deleted by the Roomba, because it was downvoted and closed (for being off-topic). Particularly for an off-topic question, it would seem strange if you would keep rep for answering a question that doesn't belong on the site.

No it would seem strange that there would be no effect on the reputation score even though the answer gets deleted along with the question. What is extra strange is that the site is as neutral and lawful as it can be when it comes to taking away and restoring reputation points... except that it has a cut off point, all of a sudden it has a need to be nice and make a very simple and fair system quite difficult. But that's Stack Overflow, they leave wrenches lying around everywhere.
